# Python, Pycharm get code completion from dynamic variables

Tags: python, pycharm

```
class FooBar:
    attribute_map = {
        "foo": "bar",
        "bar": "foo"
    }

    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, "foo", "bar")
        setattr(self, "bar", "foo")


foo_bar = FooBar()
print(foo_bar.foo)
print(foo_bar.bar)
```

I have code that looks something like this. I want pycharm to use the attribute map to display auto-completion for the dynamic variables foo and bar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. PyCharm's autocomplete does not support dynamically set attributes.

You can do type annotation like this instead:

```py
class FooBar:
    foo: str
    bar: str

    attribute_map = {
        "foo": "bar",
        "bar": "foo"
    }

    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, "foo", "bar")
        setattr(self, "bar", "foo")


foo_bar = FooBar()
print(foo_bar.foo)
print(foo_bar.bar)
```